# Add header to <dl>

Tags: html, css

I have a `<dl>` and I would like to add a header to it.

My [first attempt](http://nathandewitt.net/SO_errors/dl.html) is not successful - I don't know how to get the `<dt>` header to span both the subsequent `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements.

```
<style>
dl.table-display{
    float: left; width: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; 
    font-size: 13px; 
    line-height: 20px;
}
dt.list_header  {
    text-align: center; 
    color: white; 
    width:100%; 
    background-color: #3061B7;
}
.table-display dt{
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
.table-display dd{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<dl class="table-display">
    <dt class="list_header">Header</dt>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Title</dd>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Title</dd>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Title</dd>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Title</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just put an <h2> or <h3> tag above the <dl>? It would be more semantically correct.

Answer (score 0):

http://w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5

(also, FFR, [doctype declarations are important](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) [AKA [valid code is important](http://validator.w3.org/)])

Comment: what's the problem with my markup?  are you complaining because I only gave you the dl and the style?

Comment: I'm mentioning that you will likely have problems in the future if you don't use valid markup.

Comment: do you add that to all your HTML questions, or did you have a specific problem with mine because I didn't include the full html page?

Comment: No; I don't have a problem — you have (in that your code has).  I thought I'd let you know, because friends don't let friends waste time debugging CSS in quirks mode.

Comment: i just posted the relevant snippet: the `dl` tag and the `style` info. i am fully aware that this was not a full html page.  do you also tell people their code won't compile when they only post a snippet?

Comment: Apples and oranges.  Linking to a live example that doesn't have a doctype declaration and asking for how to accomplish a particular rendering via CSS is indicative of not realizing how important doctype declarations are to CSS rendering.  Ask anyone.

Comment: This is pretty much a link-only answer.

Comment: @M.Justin And hyperlinks on the internet are bad. Gotcha.

Comment: @reisio No, but answers which consist of just hyperlinks on the Internet have been decided by the Stack Overflow community to be bad answers.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info